# How to use constants for displaying labels in UI coded in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display the labels on my page from some constants/properties/json file. Can someone suggest how to implement this in angular 7.

The aim is that when a user wants to change the text one of the labels in the html, rather than changing it in the html file, I should be able to change in the constants/json/properties file and the same will reflect in all html pages wherever applicable.
For example,  {{lblManage}} 
And in some other file, lblManage = Manage Task.

Comment: in html file
<div>
        <h3>
          {{fetchConstant(lblManage)}}
        </h3>
</div>

in ts file
{
lblManage = Manage Task
}

it's just an example, the fetchConstant() method should fetch the value for lblMAnage which will be displayed on screen.

in html file
    <div>
        <h3>
          {{fetchConstant(lblManage)}}
          //Manage Task
        </h3>
    </div>

in ts file
    {
      lblManage = Manage Task
    }

it's just an example, the fetchConstant() method should fetch the value for lblMAnage which will be displayed on screen.

Comment: if you want it for multiple language you can use https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: What problem are you **really** trying to solve here.

Comment: Sounds like question is updated

Comment: You want to change the label for session only ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular automatically provides environment constant files

/YourApp/src/environments/environment.ts -> used for non prod, say simple use of ng serve.

and

/YourApp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts -> used for prod, usage of ng build --prod

For instance, environment.ts

```
export const environment = {  
 production: false,
 apiUrl: 'http://example.com/api'
};
```

You can simply add properties in there and use them throughout your code later like such:

```
import { environment } from './environment';
...
apiURL = environment.apiUrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part

**The aim is that when a user wants to change the text one of the labels in the html, rather than changing it in the html file, I should be able to change in the constants/json/properties file and the same will reflect in all html pages wherever applicable. For example, {{lblManage}} And in some other file, lblManage = Manage Ta**
As suggested earlier constants can be declared in environment.ts file and if you want to make it changing then use the **store concept ** . where variable store in environment file can be stored in store and update on request.

Reducer file:

```
export interface ConstantState {
url: any
}



   export const initialState: ConstantState = {
        url:'http://hello.com'
        }

export function constantReducer(
  state: constantState = initialState,
  action: constantAction
): BookingState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_STATE': {
      state = {
        ...state,

      };

      break;
    }
    case 'SET_STATE': {
      return {
        ...state,
        url:action.payload
      };
      break;
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

ACtion FILE

import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

```
export enum COnstantActionTypes {
  GetCOnstant = '[Constant] Get',
  SetConstant = '[Constant] Set'
}

export class GetCOnstant implements Action {
  readonly type = COnstantActionTypes.GetCOnstant;
}

export class SetConstant implements Action {
  readonly type = COnstantActionTypes.SetConstant;
```

constructor(payload: any){}
    }

```
export type COnstantAction = GetCOnstant | SetConstant;
```

Create a selector
const getConstantState = createFeatureSelector('constatentState');

so we can dispatch action on the required page when we update the constant  , and to get we can use the selector method .
**Moreover constant  implies we cant change the value so we have to name accordingly**

Answer (score 0):

You can read your json file like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class readJSONService{

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.readJSON().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    public readJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/constants/properties/json");
    }
}
```

And then use the created service like this.

```
   label: any;

   constructor(private readJSONService: readJSONService) {
      this.label = this.fetchConstant(lblMAnage);
```

}

```
   fetchConstant(lblMAnage){
       this.readJSONService.readJSON().subscribe((yourLabel)=> {
            console.log(yourLabel);
            this.label = yourLabel.lblMAnage;
        });
   }
```

Comment: How do I access this in html file without creating one variable for each label?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the labels on my page from some constants/properties/json file then simply use the environment files under the environment folder  or if internatinalization is preferred then i18n.

And then by import use in the component for example if we use the first approach the

```
import { environment } from './environment';
```

and access it as

```
environment.constant_name
```

Comment: how do I access this in html file, I don't want to create multiple variables, one for each label.

Comment: import environment in your .ts file (component) and get in variable and access  in html like in .ts file var constant = environment.constant_name; and in html {{constant}}

Comment: I want to access this in html file, {{environment.constant_name}},